# Isearch + Dired fast navigation

Tags: dired, hooks, isearch, events, function-key

After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471835/emacs-dired-mode-and-isearch) and one of its comments, I am trying to implement the following convenient search pattern in `dired`:

1. Press `C-s` to start `isearch`
2. Type the substring I am looking for
3. Possibly jump between all matching results by typing `C-s` repeatedly
4. Press the "Enter" key to enter the file (or folder) highlighted by `isearch`

I'm doing it with the following snippet:

```lisp
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 
  (lambda ()
    (when (and (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
               (not isearch-mode-end-hook-quit)
               (eq last-input-event ?\r)
               )
      (dired-find-file))))
```

Unfortunately the `(eq last-input-event ?\r)` bit does not appear to work: pressing "Enter" just exits `isearch` (default behavior), and I have to press it again to enter the file. For some reason `?\r` does not capture my "Enter" key. To verify this is not caused by some other part of my `emacs` configuration I deactivated most of it, but to no avail.

Additionally, I would be interested to hear whether there is some other approach to search files in `dired` which convenience can be comparable to the one described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `\r` to `'return`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 
  (lambda ()
    (when (and (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
               (not isearch-mode-end-hook-quit)
               (eq last-input-event 'return)) ; <==========
      (dired-find-file))))
```

(But it's better to use a named, not anonymous, function as a hook function. Easier to remove it etc.)

---

`C-h k` <kbd>Enter</kbd> says that `RET` is `translated from <return>`.

Elisp manual node [Function Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html) says:

> Most keyboards also have “function keys”—keys that have names or symbols
> that are not characters.  Function keys are represented in Emacs Lisp as
> symbols; **the symbol’s name is the function key’s label, in lower case**.
> For example, pressing a key labeled `<F1>` generates an input event
> represented by the symbol `f1`.

So function key `<return>` generates the input event represented by symbol `return`.